# How to get the current python interpreter path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am wondering how to get the current python interpreter path,because of the script is packed to binary file. `sys.executable` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a `PyInstaller` executable ("one-file bundle" in official terms), a temporarily created file acts as the launcher for the Python engine as explained in [How the One-File Program Works](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works), so `sys.executable` returning it makes perfect sense.

If you're interested in the compound file instead, [it's in `argv[0]`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0), as it was written on the command line (i.e. may be either a relative or absolute path or contain symlinks). So, the bundle is at `os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])`.

You won't get a path to the system's resident Python here because it's not involved in any way.